# Excel RANDBETWEEN allow one duplicate

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I’m pretty advanced in Excel, VBA, but I’m running into an issue trying to figure out how I can use the RANDBETWEEN formula and allow only 1 duplicate.

Example: I have a list of 50 people. I need to be able to give each person a number between 1-25 but the number can only appear once. So two people will have the number 1. Two people will have the number 2 and so on....

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

[`RANDBETWEEN`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RANDBETWEEN-function-4cc7f0d1-87dc-4eb7-987f-a469ab381685) doesn't work like that.  It just returns a random number between two specified numbers.  (If it only assigned a number once it wouldn't be random!)

If you need to randomly assign a list of 'somethings' (ie., numbers 1 to 25, numbers 1 to 25 twice, colours, names, files, etc etc) a quick way to do it is like this:

Basically just,

1. make a list of all possibilities in a single column (each item appearing as often as necessary),
2. add a second column that just contains `=RAND()` next to each possible number, and
3. **Sort** the list based on the column with `RAND()`.

[image: randlist]

---

`RAND()` returns a [pseudo-random number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) **between 0 and 1**.

Therefore, `RANDBETWEEN (x,y)` is exactly the same as `INT(RAND()*y)+x`.

*Just to confuse matters,* the identical function in VBA is spelled [`RND()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/rnd-function).

- More on random numbers (from worksheet or VBA) from [Chip Pearson's site](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/randomnumbers.aspx).
- Randomize anything (including [lists](https://www.random.org/lists/)) the lazy way, at [random.org](https://www.random.org/).

Comment: For the OP's specific case, the numbers to be entered in column D will be 1 to 25, and then 1 to 25 (i.e. two sets of 1-25 rather than just one set) but, other than that, I think this is the best way to do this.

Comment: Assuming x and y are positive integers the equivalent of RANDBETWEEN(x,y) is actually `=INT(RAND()*(y-x+1))+x`

Comment: @ashleedawg what do you use to create the screen grab to gif?? I upvoted!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your names are in the range A2:A51 (50 names) and you want to assign random numbers in the corresponding range B2:B51, then you may try something like this...

```
Sub getRandomNumbers(ByVal Rng As Range, ByVal bottomNum As Integer, topNum As Integer)
Dim i As Long, Num As Integer
Rng.Cells.Clear
For i = 1 To Rng.Cells.Count
    Num = Application.RandBetween(bottomNum, topNum)
    Do While Application.CountIf(Rng, Num) = 2
        Num = Application.RandBetween(bottomNum, topNum)
    Loop
    Rng.Cells(i) = Num
Next i
End Sub
```

Provided you have above procedure on a Standard Module, you may call it after passing the destination range, bottom number and the top number parameters to it like below...

```
Sub AssignRandomNumbers()
getRandomNumbers Range("B2:B51"), 1, 25
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I got it working with your example, but here is the issue. I have names on A5-however many... I then have how many side pots they want in on column B. C-V (20) is a random number between 1 AND however many pots people signed up for / 2(i'm assuming)....

What I need is to take all the people in the list SUM all the POTS everyone got in * 2, then on each # column get a random number between 1-xx*2. Each number would have to appear no more than 2 times, but MUST appear 2 times..... I hope this makes sense....

Comment: You're welcome! Glad you got it working. You are lucky enough to get answers even without posting what you tried. So I would suggest you to accept the answer and mark your question as Solved. And then open a New Question with your new requirement along with the code which is working for you. Also, highlight the key cells/columns on the sheet and share the screenshot and describe those key cells/columns in the question description as well and also post a screenshot of how your desired output should look like.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do this with a single formula if you want.....

Assuming names in `A2:A51` and `B1` containing a header or blank you can use this formula in `B2` copied down

`=AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(INDIRECT("1:25"))*{1,1}/(COUNTIF(B$1:B1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:25")))<{1,2}),RANDBETWEEN(1,51-ROWS(B$1:B1)))`

I used a `COUNTIF` formula in column F just to check that there were 2 of each number

[image]